# How can I make a list of values "remember" the entered parameters?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I generate a list of values for r using:

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := 
  Reduce[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 4 == 0, r];
Evaluate[(s[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])]
```

I wish to then use these values of r in another function:

```
0.5 - 0.2 r PlusMinus[Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2]]
```

I'm not sure how to do this while having the values of r "remember" the value of the parameter d that the r was calculated with. I thought of trying to combine the functions, but I end up solving both parts with each value of d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to save the `d` along with the solution at the location it is generated.

So instead of just returning `{r1,r2,r3...}` solutions, you return `{{d,r1},{d,r2},...}`

So the data is always together in one list. Then when you run your code `0.5 - 0.2 r PlusMinus[Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2]]`  now you run it against the list which has both `d` and `r` in it.

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := Module[{res},
   res = Last[#] & /@ List @@ Reduce[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^2) r - 4 == 0, r];
   {d, #} & /@ res
   ];
rValues = Flatten[s[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1], 1]
```

This generates

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the above, the first entry is `d` and the second is `r` solution.  Now simply do the following, where `#[[1]]` is the `d` and `#[[2]]` is the `r` in each sublist.

```
(0.5 - 0.2 #[[2]] PlusMinus[ Sqrt[0.01 #[[2]]^2 - #[[1]]^2]]) & /@ rValues
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 4 == 0, r]
rvalues = Join @@ (Transpose /@ Table[{Array[d &, Length[s[d]]], s[d]}, {d, 0, 1, 0.1}])
```

The above code generates the same output as the Nasser's code:

[image]

Proceeding as @Nasser did, we get:

```
(0.5 - 0.2 #[[2]]*PlusMinus[Sqrt[0.01 #[[2]]^2 - #[[1]]^2]]) & /@ rvalues
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to plot (d, lambda), where lambda is the final list of items from this post. This wouldn't be a complex plot, instead I want to plot the y-values as the magnitudes of the real and imaginary components of each value of lambda, using color or otherwise to signify the difference. @Nasser

Comment: @ξύλο it would be better to make a new question post asking that new question, rather than attempting to modify or completely change this current question post. I think it would make for a great question that you can link to this question from! Then you can get an answer specific to that sort of topic (plotting & such), as well as get an answer specific to the topic of this question!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[s]
s[d_?NumericQ] := Module[{roots, r},
  roots = {ToRules[
     Reduce[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 4 == 0, r]]};
  (*Echo[roots];*)
  0.5 - 0.2 r PlusMinus[Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2]] /. roots
  ]

Evaluate[(s[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])]
```