# How can I plot a list of complex numbers against a parameter while separating their real and imaginary parts?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, complex

This is a sort of continuation of [How can I make a list of values "remember" the entered parameters?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277845/how-can-i-make-a-list-of-values-remember-the-entered-parameters/277853?noredirect=1#comment693973_277853)

I have some cubic function which solves for a variable `r` for different values of a parameter `d`:

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := 
 SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 4 == 0, r]
rvalues = 
 Join @@ (Transpose /@ 
    Table[{Array[d &, Length[s[d]]], s[d]}, {d, 0, 0.02, 0.001}])
```

and generates the following list in the form `{d,r}`

[image]

Now I input this list into another function that solves for some eigenvalues where  where `#[[1]]` is the `d` and `#[[2]]` is the `r`:

```
(0.5 - 0.2 #[[2]] + 
    PlusMinus[Sqrt[0.01 #[[2]]^2 - #[[1]]^2]]) & /@ rvalues
```

which generates

[image]

I would like to create a scatter plot for this list where the x-variable is `d`, and the y-variable is the magnitude of the eigenvalues.

I can imagine something like

```
LambdaRe = ListPlot[{{d_1,lambda_1},...,{d_i,lambda_i}} ];
LambdaIm = ListPlot[{...},PlotStyle->Red];

Show[LambdaRe,LambdaIm]
```

It is important to note that I want to plot each complex eigenvalue as two separate values, ignoring the imaginary part i and simply plotting each magnitude in a different color or otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s[d_?NumericQ] := SolveValues[r^3 - 10 r^2 + (25 + 100*d^{2}) r - 4 == 0, r]
eigenfunc[{d_, r_}] := {d, (0.5 - 0.2 r + # Sqrt[0.01 r^2 - d^2])} & /@ {1, -1};

rvalues = Join @@ (Transpose /@ 
  Table[{Array[d &, Length[s[d]]], s[d]}, {d, 0, 0.2, 0.01}]);

eigenvalues = Catenate[eigenfunc /@ rvalues];

ListPlot[{
  MapAt[Re, eigenvalues, {All, 2}], 
  MapAt[Im, eigenvalues, {All, 2}]
 }, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

Comment: Where do the vertical bars come from?

Comment: They come from ``Around`` (your ``PlusMinus``).

Comment: The ```PlusMinus``` comes from the quadratic formula (used to find the eigenvalues). I didn't mean for it to be the error of the calculation. Is there a way to plot it as such (two values rather than a central value with bars)?

Comment: Oh, okay, I have fixed it.